# Windows 8 XAML speed issues

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've been writing a Windows 8 Store XAML/C# application and during testing on a Windows Surface device found that the application was very slow navigating between pages.

The application follows the MVVM pattern and uses SQLite. My first thoughts were it would be the data access to SQLite that was slowing things down.

I've stripped all my c# code and data access code out so I'm just left with a XAML shell.

After doing this I still found that the pages where slow to load when navigating between them.

I have about 60 controls on one page (TextBoxes, Combos and CheckBox) so I wouldn't say that's anything major and it takes 1-2 seconds to load. That might not sound much but it is a notable pause and that is without any data access code.

Does anybody have any tips to make the XAML pages draw/load quicker?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these controls all visible at the same time? If not, then you should use virtualization and avoid containers that don't support it (as far as I remember, e.g. groupable SemanticZoom does not virtualize the items).

Comment: 60 controls sounds a little heavy to have loaded all at once. Are you able to cut this down? Consider using virtualization so that you don't have to show all of them at once.

Comment: It's basically a data entry form and all the controls are within a Grid and the grid is within a scrollviewer. So the user goes through all the controls before moving to the next page. Only 15 controls are visible within the scroll viewer and the user scolls to see more. Can I virtualize the loading of the controls within the grid as it scrolls? I have other pages too which have half the controls and they are slow. Thanks for your replys.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you won't be able to virtualize anything if you keep you Grid + ScrollViewer as your root container for the page.

However, you could replace this Grid + ScrollViewer, by a GridView (which supports scrolling by default), and set the GridView.ItemsPanel to a VirtualizingStackPanel.

This will require a bit of refactoring to your code.

One solution, would be to split your form, into "groups" of controls. For example if the goal of your form is to edit a user profile, you could have a "Personnal Informations" group, and "Profesionnal Informations" group.
Once you have a Group-hierarchy for you form, just bind your GridView to these groups, and the virtualizingStackPanel will do the job of only showing/instanciating the controls to be displayed.